# Remove certain polygon from SpatialPolygonDataFrame

Tags: shapefile, r, sp

I am using R *maptools* library to parse the shapefile into a list of polygons. The function [readShapeSpatial](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/maptools/docs/readShapeSpatial)

```
shp <- readShapeSpatial("<path to my shapefile>")
```

gives me a [SpatailPolygonDataFrame](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/as.data.frame.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame) object. In my example, my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame has the following columns:

```
> names(shp)
[1] "AREA"       "PERIMETER"  "COMAREA_"   "COMAREA_ID" "AREA_NUMBE"
[6] "COMMUNITY"  "AREA_NUM_1" "SHAPE_AREA" "SHAPE_LEN
```

I know that I can remove certain polygons by their `row.id`, e.g.

```
shp.dropI  <- shp[-i, ]
shp.subset <- shp[i %in% c(1,2,3),]
```

Now I want to drop certain polygon(s) with a condition, say `AREA > 10`. How do I implement this elegantly? The only method I have now is to iterate through all rows and find corresponding `row.id`.

Comment: Be wary of "AREA" attributes. There's no guarantee that's the actual area, right? You can use rgeos::gArea(x, byid = TRUE) to calculate it, and rgdal::spTransform if you need to change projection for that calculation.

Comment: @mdsumner you are completely right. Good point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I would highly recommend using readOGR, from the rgdal library, to read your shapefile. It will retain the projection information (proj4string) and save numerous headaches, when string matching, using other functions.

Two quick ways to accomplish what your are after are using an index or using subset. This will retain polygons with an area < 10 (dropping those > 10).

```
shp.sub <- shp[shp$AREA < 10,] 
shp.sub <- subset(shp, AREA < 10)
```

Comment: Nice! I just realized this question could be generalized into "how to select certain rows in DataFrame with R". And thanks for the suggestion too